# ChartJSのTooltip callback関数が動作しません。

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

ChartJSを使って棒グラフの表示を行っております。
ツールチップの内容を編集するため、tooltipsプロパティにcallbacksを定義しましたが、
ツールチップの中身が変わりません。原因はお判りでしょうか。

▼実行環境
OS：Windows10
ブラウザ：Chrome 90.0.4430.93
ChartJS：ver2.8

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    
var barChartData = {
        labels : [ "1月", "2月", "3月", "4月", "5月", "6月", "7月" ],
        datasets : [ {
            type : 'bar',
            label : "売上",
            data : [ 4000, 4850, 5900, 6210, 2500, 4000, 6500 ],
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)'
        } ]
    };

var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
    {
        type : 'bar',
        data : barChartData,
        options : {
            tooltips : {
                callbacks : {
                    title : function() {
                        return 'テストタイトル';
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script crossorigin 
 src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザのキャッシュをクリアしてページを再読み込みしたところ、反映が行われました。